Voltage Divider wrong result - EasyEda
I have the following schematic loaded in EasyEda Simulator mode. For some reason I get 3.615v instead of the 2.93v.
Am I doing something wrong, or is the simulator just messing with me?


From the picture XMM1 is displaying 3.615 mV, rather than 3.615 V as mentioned in the question text. I.e. a factor of 1000 lower. What are the settings for VCC and XMM1 in EasyEda?

Which makes things even more strage. Settings for V are 12.4V and XMM1 set as Voltmeter.

It looks like EasyEda is not liking the capital K at the lower resistor. If you calculate it for 6.8 Ohm, the voltage divider should give ~3.8 mV.

That was it! Now it shows 2.928V :)
